NonExistentTimeError error when converting pandas dataframe to pyspark dataframe
I am querying a database in InfluxDB. The database has the date in timestamp format. With this code I make the query
query = f"select  * from {measurement} where time > '2021-03-28T02:02:58Z' AND time < 
'2021-03-28T02:05:00Z'"
result = client.query(query)
df_pandas = pd.DataFrame(list(result.get_points()))
df_pandas.head(20)


Then I do some transformations
df_pandas_filtered = df_pandas[['time', 'idDispositivo', 'idSensor', 'valor']]
df_pandas_filtered.loc[:,'time'] = df_pandas_filtered['time'].str.slice(0, 19)
df_pandas_filtered.loc[:,'time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_pandas_filtered['time'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')

df_pandas_filtered['time'] = df_pandas_filtered['time'].astype("datetime64[ns]")

df_pandas_filtered.loc[:,'idDispositivo'] = pd.to_numeric(df_pandas_filtered['idDispositivo'],errors='coerce').astype('Int64').replace({pd.NA: None})
df_pandas_filtered.loc[:,'idSensor'] = pd.to_numeric(df_pandas_filtered['idSensor'],errors='coerce').astype('Int64').replace({pd.NA: None})
df_pandas_filtered.loc[:,'valor'] = pd.to_numeric(df_pandas_filtered['valor'],errors='coerce').astype('Int64').replace({pd.NA: None})
df_pandas_filtered.head(20)


The error occurs when I transform to a pyspark dataframe
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df_pandas_filtered, schema=schema)
spark_df.show()

NonExistentTimeError                      Traceback (most recent call last) Cell In[61], line 2
      1 # Convierte el Pandas DataFrame en un DataFrame de PySpark
----> 2 spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df_pandas_filtered, schema=schema)
      3 spark_df.show()

File C:\spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\sql\session.py:1440, in SparkSession.createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)    1436     data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=column_names)    1438 if has_pandas and isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame):    1439     # Create a DataFrame from pandas DataFrame.
-> 1440     return super(SparkSession, self).createDataFrame(  # type: ignore[call-overload]    1441         data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema    1442     )    1443 return self._create_dataframe(    1444     data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema  # type: ignore[arg-type]    1445 )

File C:\spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\sql\pandas\conversion.py:362, in SparkConversionMixin.createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    360             warn(msg)
    361             raise
--> 362 converted_data = self._convert_from_pandas(data, schema, timezone)
    363 return self._create_dataframe(converted_data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)

File C:\spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\sql\pandas\conversion.py:474, in SparkConversionMixin._convert_from_pandas(self, pdf, schema, timezone) ... File c:\Users\raidel.rodriguez\.conda\envs\data_summary\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\tzconversion.pyx:177, in pandas._libs.tslibs.tzconversion.tz_localize_to_utc_single()

File c:\Users\raidel.rodriguez\.conda\envs\data_summary\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\tzconversion.pyx:417, in pandas._libs.tslibs.tzconversion.tz_localize_to_utc()

NonExistentTimeError: 2021-03-28 02:02:58 

I know it has to do with the change of summer time in my time zone (Central Europe). I have checked that on the date 2021-03-28 the time change was made in Spain. But I don't know how to fix it and I need help
Thanks in advance
